# How to access component scope from private functions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I couldn't figure it out. I saw that some solutions like exporting it to the window  object and getting from there but I feel like there is an easy way that I don't know:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      uploadScanningDialog: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    skipScan() {
      hideDialog();
    },
  },
}

function hideDialog() {
  this.uploadScanningDialog = false;
}
```

So this is the basic scenario. But when I run tests, **this** is undefined inside my **hideDialog** function. I don't want to move every function to public scope which is under the methods. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing within method `skipScan` `this` is defined as expected. So you could call `hideDialog` with bound context like following

```
skipScan() {
  hideDialog.call(this);
},
```

see also https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call and https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply